# How to update tags on a pivot table Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to edit an article, to do that I do have an `update()` method on my controller, the thing is that I can update the title, body date of the article without any problem, however article tags I can not update them in the right way.

Meaning when I update and select some new articles I want the old one to be removed and updated with the new selected ones, but instead when I try the code below I get the new and old tags together. Note I do have a pivot table called article_tags.

My update method on my controller:

```
public function update(Article $articles,  ArticleRequest $request)
{
    //update the article
    $articles->update($request->all());

    //attach new tags to the article 
    $articles->tags()->attach($request->input('tag_list'));

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

note `tags()` its a `manyToMany()` relationship on `Tag` model. Any idea how can I update the tags on the right way remove the old tags with new tags ?!

Answer (score 1):

You need Sync so try this

```
public function update(Article $articles,  ArticleRequest $request)
{
    //update the article
    $articles->update($request->all());

    //attach new tags to the article 
    $articles->tags()->sync($request->input('tag_list'));

    return redirect('articles');
}
```